# TSQL Multiple Updates to the same row from a 1-to-N relationship

Tags: t-sql

I have the following table:

```
Message ID, Message, TextID, Text
1,'First name:{0}; Last name:{1}', 0, 'John'
1,'First name:{0}; Last name:{1}', 1, 'Doe'
2,'Address: {0}; City: {1}; Country: {2}',0,'Maple Str. 1'
2,'Address: {0}; City: {1}; Country: {2}',1,'New York'
2,'Address: {0}; City: {1}; Country: {2}',2,'USA'
```

I need a query that selects:

```
'First name: John; Last name: Doe'
'Address: Maple Str.1; City: New York; Country: USA'
```

Since I don't know in advance how many placeholders there are in each Message, I can't do something like N joins between the table and itself (unless I estimate that the max number of placeholders is 20 and i do 20 join but this is sooo horrible!)

Is there something like a recursive CTE that groups the rows by IDMessage and start updating the Message with the replace?

Comment: You can do this with a recursive CTE by cycling each TextID in order and doing replaces of the placeholders. Please note that Message and Text should be in different tables, so you don't repeat your message for each text you need to replace.

Comment: I actually have two different tables, one for messages and one for texts. Here I put them togheter in order to simplify the exposition of the presentation.

The recursive CTE's I saw so far always add new rows ( i used them to go throuth hierarchies) so I excluded them. If you say it is possible with them I will try to wrap my head around a recursive CTE that doesn't use the usual "anchor table". Thank you

To be honest, I have even more than two tables because I denormalized everything, but i avoided to talk about that otherwise the question would have been too complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can guide with the following example. We use a recursive CTE to replace the message with each placeholder value, then show only the latest version.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Message') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Message

CREATE TABLE #Message (
    MessageID INT,
    Message VARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO #Message (
    MessageID,
    Message)
VALUES
    (1, 'First name:{0}; Last name:{1}'),
    (2, 'Address: {0}; City: {1}; Country: {2}')

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Text') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Text

CREATE TABLE #Text (
    MessageID INT,
    TextPlaceholder INT,
    Text VARCHAR(100)
    PRIMARY KEY (MessageID, TextPlaceholder))

INSERT INTO #Text (
    MessageID,
    TextPlaceholder,
    Text)
VALUES
    (1, 0, 'John'),
    (1, 1, 'Doe'),
    (2, 0, 'Maple Str. 1'),
    (2, 1, 'New York'),
    (2, 2, 'USA')


;WITH MaxPlaceholderByMessage AS
(
    SELECT
        M.MessageID,
        MaxPlaceholder = MAX(T.TextPlaceholder)
    FROM
        #Message AS M
        INNER JOIN #Text AS T ON M.MessageID = T.MessageID
    GROUP BY
        M.MessageID
),
 RecursiveReplacePlaceholders AS
(
    SELECT
        MessageID = M.MessageID,
        ReplacedMessage = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), M.Message),
        CurrentPlaceholder = -1
    FROM
        #Message AS M

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        MessageID = R.MessageID,
        ReplacedMessage = REPLACE(
            R.ReplacedMessage, 
            '{' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), T.TextPlaceholder) + '}',
            T.Text),
        CurrentPlaceholder = T.TextPlaceholder
    FROM
        RecursiveReplacePlaceholders AS R
        INNER JOIN #Text AS T ON
            R.MessageID = T.MessageID AND
            R.CurrentPlaceholder + 1 = T.TextPlaceholder
)
SELECT
    R.MessageID,
    R.ReplacedMessage
FROM
    RecursiveReplacePlaceholders AS R
    LEFT JOIN MaxPlaceholderByMessage AS M ON R.MessageID = M.MessageID
WHERE
    M.MaxPlaceholder = R.CurrentPlaceholder OR
    M.MessageID IS NULL -- There is no text available to replace
ORDER BY
    R.MessageID

/*
Result:

    MessageID   ReplacedMessage
    1           First name:John; Last name:Doe
    2           Address: Maple Str. 1; City: New York; Country: USA
*/
```

If you have missing texts for a placeholder, you will have to change a little the recursive condition to cycle up to the max placeholder available.

Comment: Ahh, now I see... you are actually adding a lot of rows too with the UNION but then you are keeping only the last added... this was what I could not understand how to do.

I actually solved in a different way. For each row I calculated the index where the replacement will take place.
Then using LAG and LEAD I find which is the replacement point of the texts before and after each text.
Now I divide with SUBSTRING the Message in N messages, each one with one replacement. Then I use the code that takes several rows and concatenate them (using FOR XML PATH)